# PHP - send two fields through mail

Tags: php

I have a document with 2 textboxes and 1 submit button. I want to send an email when I press the submit button and in it should be the value of the textboxes. My PHP knowledge is a bit dusty. I don't want to bother the user with the emailproces, so he can't see this and should just be redirected.

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="section_form" id="usernameSection"> 
<label for="username">Login:</label> 
<input size="20" type="text" name="username" id="username" /> 
</div> 

<div class="section_form" id="emailSection"> 
<label for="email">Email:</label> 
<input size="20" type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="20"/> 
</div> 

<div id="submit_button"> 
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='bottom';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='top';" onclick="return SetFocus();">Submit</button> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your task.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $message = "username : $username ; email : $email";
    $to = "your@email.com";
    $subject  = "Email Subject";
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
    ?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="form1">
<div class="section_form" id="usernameSection"> 
<label for="username">Login:</label> 
<input size="20" type="text" name="username" id="username" /> 
</div> 

<div class="section_form" id="emailSection"> 
<label for="email">Email:</label> 
<input size="20" type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="20"/> 
</div> 

<div id="submit_button"> 
<button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='bottom';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='top';" onclick="return SetFocus();">Submit</button> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP mail function - listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

That should be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the core of what you're looking for is

```
<?php
// Check that all fields are present, construct the message body, etc
mail($to, $subject, $body);
header("Location: wherever.php");
exit();
?>
```

See the [mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in PHP documentation. (Also, thank you Alex for the `exit()` reminder.)

Comment: Don't forget to `exit` after sending the `Location` header.

Comment: Location redirects me right? And how would you bind username and email to $message?

Comment: See ssapkota's answer for that - basically use `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['email']` after some validation.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:
- [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
- [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Also you need to check: [Forms in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), you might want to use `form` to send the data of input fields to server.